# Add a class to every 4th div in loop

Tags: php, loops, modulus, modular

Here is my code:

```
<? for($x = 0; $x < count($groupSmall); $x++){ ?>
    <div class="col-md-3 meeting-item">
        <img src="images/image.jpg" />
    </div>
<? } ?>
```

I would like to add a new class to every 4th div in this loop. I know it can be done with Modulus but I can't get it to work.

Thanks!!!

Comment: If you know it, try it. If it does not work, show what you've tried.

Comment: I see no sign of modulus attempt in your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php modulus in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135404/php-modulus-in-a-loop)

Answer (score 2):

```
<? for($x = 0; $x < count($groupSmall); $x++){ ?>
    <div class="col-md-3 meeting-item <?= $x % 4 === 0 ? 'my-class' : null ?>">
        <img src="images/image.jpg" />
    </div>
<? } ?>
```

[PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php)

Comment: Hi Oswaldo, thank you for your reply. It looks like the class is being added to the first div. Is there a way for it to be added to the 4th, 8th, 16th, and so on?

Comment: Change the `$x % 4 === 0` to `$x % 4 === 3`

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use nth-child(4n)? [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ggmkj/).

```
<? for($x = 0; $x < count($groupSmall); $x++){ ?>
    <div class="col-md-3 meeting-item">
        <img src="images/image.jpg" />
    </div>
<? } ?>
```

...remains unchanged. And in your CSS:

```
div.meeting-item:nth-child(4n){
    background-color:#EEE;
}
```

Comment: @jeroen Meant to write 4n+4 :/

Comment: Not to nitpick, but that's the same as just `4n` ;-)

Comment: @jeroen Didn't actually know that :) Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I guess I didn't want to use css due the whole IE8 issue

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on Oswaldo's answer because I don't have the reputation yet, but if you just replace the "0" by a 3, as so, you'll get the class added to the 4th 8th etc.

```
<? for($x = 0; $x < count($groupSmall); $x++){ ?>
    <div class="col-md-3 meeting-item <?= $x % 4 === 3 ? 'my-class' : null ?>">
    <img src="images/image.jpg" />
</div>
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You souldn't use PHP for this kind of stuff. That's what CSS is for. Let's say you have a container and the divs inside, the container is `divContainer`. So, in CSS:

```
#divContainer div .meeting-item:nth-child(4n+4){
   //apply style.
 }
```