# php array and for loop - add <br> after 5 resultss

Tags: php, arrays

This is my code:

```
$sm2 = array( "angry", "cool", "cry", "happy", "heart", "kiss", "mute", "sad", "smile"); 

for($j=0;$j<count($sm2); $j++) {
    $data=$data . "<img id='". $sm2[$j] ."' src='images/emotions/" . $sm2[$j] . ".png' data-toggle='tooltip' title=". $sm2[$j] ."  width='32' height='32' style='margin:5px;'
    onclick='insertEmoticons(this.id);'/>";
}
```

How can I insert a `<br>` tag after 5 results because i don't want everything to be on one row.

Comment: modulus `($i % 5 == 0)` - as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135404/php-modulus-in-a-loop which this is also a possible duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).

```
<?php
$sm2 = array( "angry", "cool", "cry", "happy", "heart", "kiss", "mute", "sad", "smile"); 
for($j=0;$j<count($sm2); $j++) {
     if(!empty($j) && $j % 5 == 0) {
          echo '<br>';
     }
     echo $sm2[$j];
}
```

Output:

```
angrycoolcryhappyheart<br>kissmutesadsmile
```

Demo: https://eval.in/614166

Or with your actual code:

```
for($j=0;$j<count($sm2); $j++) {
    if(!empty($j) && $j % 5 == 0) {
          $data .= '<br>';
    }
    $data=$data . "<img id='". $sm2[$j] ."' src='images/emotions/" . $sm2[$j] . ".png' data-toggle='tooltip' title=". $sm2[$j] ."  width='32' height='32' style='margin:5px;'
    onclick='insertEmoticons(this.id);'/>";
}
```

Also note `$data=$data .` is the same as `$data .= ...`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sm2 = array( "angry", "cool", "cry", "happy", "heart", "kiss", "mute", "sad", "smile"); 

for($j=0;$j<count($sm2); $j++) {
    $data=$data . "<img id='". $sm2[$j] ."' src='images/emotions/" . $sm2[$j] . ".png' data-toggle='tooltip' title=". $sm2[$j] ."  width='32' height='32' style='margin:5px;' onclick='insertEmoticons(this.id);'/>";
    if ( (($j+1) % 5) == 0)
    {
        $data = $data . "<br>";
    }

}
```

Comment: That code mate is giving syntax error :)