# How to print something in certain position in php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to print a `<div>` class called 'first' in 1, 4, 7, 10, 13 ...... position What should i need to do it ?

```
<?php
$i=0;  
?>

<?php
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>



<div class="column dt-sc-one-third<?php if ($i==0){ ?> first <?php } ?>"> 

<p class="comments">
<a title="Comment on Latin words Ipsum" href="#">
<span class="fa fa-comment"> </span>
25
</a>
</p>


</div>


<?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
```

I want first div should have a class name called first and the 4 th div should have that class and so on.....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8135703/295783

Answer (score 2):

You can use Modulo operator of PHP. For example $i%3 divides the variable by 3 gives reminder of the divider operation as return value. So, in your case it will always gives 1 for the values 1, 4, 7, 10, 13 ...... 
Please check the below code,

```
<?php if ($i%3 == 1){ ?> first <?php } ?>
```

Please refer, http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Comment: You should add an explanation to the answer, not just "try".

Comment: it wasn't when I commented. But that's a good rule of thumb...  always add an explanation.

Comment: Sure @Magnus. I will do that in my answers

Comment: @Magnus, Not sure if it is good idea to delete my answer. I will leave my answer to be here but with explanation. I am not worrying about the downvotes. I already have kept few of my answers with negative votes, un-deleted because I think I posted correct answers. Your inputs please?

Comment: Your solution is correct, it was just missing an explanation (it's important so the OP understands why this is correct so he/she can modify it to fit better).  Now it's spot in..  upvote worhty. :)