# How to execute an action of 10 in 10 interaction PHP

Tags: php

I have an array and I would like to take action on every iteration

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
      0,1,3...10 
     // Execute
     $create->save(); 
      11, 12, 13... 20
     // Execute
     $create->save(); 
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php modulus in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135404/php-modulus-in-a-loop)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the modulo of 10.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if($i%10 == 0{
        $create->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: What this says is: if the iteration value is divisible by x (10) with no remainder (so 12 is not divisible by 10 *cleanly* as it leaves a remainder of 2). Then perform action y :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$n = 10;
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if($n == $i) {
        $create->save();
        $n = $n + 10;
    }
}
```

But here in your loops `10 != 10`, because is **11** loop. If you need to execute at every 10 loop, then `$n = 9` or `$i = 1`;